# Detecting a particular number in Android Contacts

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, telephony

I am writing an Android App in which I need to detect whether a particular number is in contact list of the user or not.
 **Approach 1:** *Query the Contacts ContentResolver for the given number.*
    **Pitfalls**
  If number is saved in contact list without Country Code (e.g. +91 in case of India) and Source number includes the country code. In that case I am unable to match it against any contact by using this approach.
  **Alternative:**  I came across a function [PhoneNumberUtils.compare (String a, String b)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
  **Questions**

1. Can I use this function safely enough in my case. (By safely I mean, will it give correct result 99% of times?)
2. This function has got 2 overloaded methods. What is the difference between the two? It is very unclear from the  [Android Develeper's documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: What do you mean by 99% of times? like do you know all the test cases?

Comment: @RJadhav: yes test cases will be like.Let HA be home country of a and HB be the home country of B. CA be the current country of A and CB be the current country of B.Now Cases are     1. HA=HB =CA=CB 2. HA=HB!=(CA=CB).  3. HA=HB,HA!=CA,CA!=CB.... like wise...

Comment: For 2nd approach, do You plan to get all contacts and compare one-by-one? Why not combine both (e.g. using query, get only N last phone digits same using SQL and after that use that API to compare only few numbers)?